# Signal Comparison with python

Tags: python, signals, analysis

From a recorded time based Panda dataset, I need to compare various signals to a reference signal. Around the reference signal I define sliding soft limits and constant hard limits. Soft limits are allowed to be crossed if it's for less time than the allowed excursion time.For a visual explanation, please see image below.

Does any existing python library perform this type of data analysis? I did a thorough search, but I couldn't find anything. Thanks.

[image: Signal Analysis]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds specific to what you are doing, and not too tricky to implement, so doing so might not be a be a bad idea :) It will also give you more freedom in the future should you need to make your analysis more complicated.